# How to calculate class_weights for Multi-class classification problem in Catboost

Tags: machine-learning, classification, multiclass-classification, catboost

I have a multi-class dataset with below class ratios

```
Class A: 61%
Class B: 34% 
Class C: 3%
```

I am using a catboost model which takes class_weight as the parameter. What is the correct way to calculate class_weights in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
from sklearn.utils import class_weight
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

ds=pd.read_csv(datafile)
y=ds.['Class'].tolist()   # y now has all the instances class labels
yu=np.unique(y)           # yu now has the class labels A, B, C
class_weight=class_weight.compute_class_weight('balanced',yu,y)
```

Now you can use **class_weight** as the class_weight parameter of catboost